# cron создает некорректные файлы логов

Tags: php, логирование, cron

Система ubuntu 18.04 linux nginx

Если выполнить команду в SSH консоли, то файл читаемый и корректный, но аналогичная команда в cron, создает нечитаемый файл.

Создал нормальный читаемый файл вида output.txt

```
SSH консоль:

php /www/mysite/filename.php > /www/mysite/output.txt
```

Создал некорректный файл вида 'output.txt'$'\r'

```
Cron
0 23 * * * php /www/mysite/filename.php > /www/mysite/output.txt
```

Постоянно приходится переименовывать файл командой, чтобы прочесть логи:

```
mv 'output.txt'$'\r' output.txt
```

Не могу найти решение, может кто сталкивался и сможете помочь? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте файл `/usr/local/bin/myfilename.sh`:

```
sudo cat > /usr/local/bin/myfilename.sh <<EOF
#!/usr/bin/sh
$(echo $(env) '/usr/bin/php /www/mysite/filename.php > /www/mysite/output.txt')
EOF
sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/myfilename.sh
```

В cron прописываете:

```
0 23 * * *   /usr/local/bin/myfilename.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

удалось воспроизвести такое поведение, добавив (в файле *crontab*) перед концом строки символ `\r` (он же `cr`, он же `carriage return`, шестнадцатиричный код `0d`). т.е., сделать «dos-овский» вариант [окончания строки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8): `\r\n`.

в программе *vim* вернуть нормальные «unix-овские» окончания строк можно командой:

```
:set ff=unix
```

файл после этого надо будет сохранить:

```
:w
```

как сделать подобное в вашем любимом редакторе — смотрите в его документации.

---

вот так выглядит файл с «unix-овским» переводом строки:

```
$ cat goodcrontab
* * * * * touch /tmp/somefile
$ hexdump -C goodcrontab
00000000  2a 20 2a 20 2a 20 2a 20  2a 20 74 6f 75 63 68 20  |* * * * * touch |
00000010  2f 74 6d 70 2f 73 6f 6d  65 66 69 6c 65 0a        |/tmp/somefile.|
0000001e
```

а вот так с «dos-овским»:

```
$ cat /tmp/wrongcrontab
* * * * * touch /tmp/somefile
$ hexdump -C /tmp/wrongcrontab
00000000  2a 20 2a 20 2a 20 2a 20  2a 20 74 6f 75 63 68 20  |* * * * * touch |
00000010  2f 74 6d 70 2f 73 6f 6d  65 66 69 6c 65 0d 0a     |/tmp/somefile..|
0000001f
```